# Agregar bordes a las palabras en expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero tener en *Javascript* una función que use expresiones regulares para agregarle cosas a los bordes de ciertas palabras de un texto.

Ejemplo, quiero reemplazar esto:

> El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña tocaba el saxofón...

... por lo siguiente, sabiendo que las palabras claves, son **veloz**, **cardillo** y **kiwi**:

> El <b>veloz</b> murciélago hindú comía feliz <b>cardillo<b> y <b>kiwi</b>. La cigüeña tocaba el saxofón...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Para esto vamos a usar el método [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) del `String` de *Javascript*, el cual recibe dos parámetros, uno es la expresión regular (patrón), y el otro es la expresión de reemplazo.

El primer argumento contiene las palabras clave, hay que [agruparlas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses) mediante la forma `(?:lista)`, entre otras cosas, para ahorrar memoria, y separadas por el *[operador de alternancia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or)* `|`, en este caso, veloz, cardillo o kiwi. Además, para separar en palabras completas, se usa [`\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) al principio y al final de la palabra.

Queda de la siguiente manera:

```
/\b(?:veloz|cardillo|kiwi)\b/gi
```

El segundo argumento tiene un signo pesos seguido de una **y estadounidense** (ampersand), se escribe `$&`, que devuelve todo el texto con el que se coincidió, y podemos agregarle los bordes que queremos a la izquierda y a la derecha, en este caso, simulando una etiqueta en negrita `<b>clave</b>`.

```
<b>$&</b>
```

La acción para reemplazar queda de la siguiente manera.

```
texto.replace(/\b(?:veloz|cardillo|kiwi)\b/gi,"<b>$&</b>")
```

Código final:

```js
function agregar_borde(texto,claves,izquierdo,derecho)
{
  var salida = claves.join("|")
  var expresión = new RegExp("\\b(?:"+salida+")\\b","gi")
  return texto.replace(expresión,izquierdo+"$&"+derecho)
}

var texto = "El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz cardillo y kiwi."+
  " La cigüeña tocaba el saxofón..."

var palabras_claves = ["veloz","cardillo","kiwi"]
  
var izquierdo="<b>"
var derecho="</b>"

var resultado=agregar_borde(texto,palabras_claves,izquierdo,derecho)

document.write(texto)
document.write("<p/>")
document.write(resultado)

console.log(texto)
console.log(resultado)
```